Error LNK1104, MSB3073 when building a project VS2019
I'm trying to collect USRP following this guide. I do not encounter errors:
Error LNK1104 cannot open file '..\lib\Debug\uhd.lib'

if you build the entire project at once.
And if you select to build only ALL_BUILD, it is going to, however, if you INSTALL it after that, an error occurs
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :end
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cm ErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
::cm ErrorLevel
exit /b %1
::cmD one
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
:VCEnd" exited with code 1. INSTALL C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets138

I tried to find solutions on the Internet, but no solutions helped. I run all programs as an administrator. There are no errors in Cmake. I hope you can help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong.
After a lot of attempts, I thought that the problem was in my Windows, decided to try to build in a virtual machine, put everything I needed, but all the same errors.
I have an assumption that I did not do something to the end, namely in the UHD Clause, I downloaded the source file, as they say in the installation, but then there is the Using PyBOMBS clause, it is for Windows or for Linux, if it is for Windows, then I will not be able to execute it, because I did not understand how to make it.

You forgot to specify which exact actions you have performed when tried to build the project (before facing the error). Make sure to specify also which version of the project you are tried to build.

@Tsyvarev I am use:
Windows: 10
Visual Studio: 2019
Cmake: 3.20.1
Boost: 1.74.0
Doxygen: 1.8.14
Git: 2.25.1
NSIS: 3.03
Python : 3.8.0
libusb: 1.0.27
UHB : 3.15.0; 4.0.0; 4.7.0
Mako: 1.2.0
ruamel.yaml: 0.16.0
request:2.25.0
